# highlight words in php and return part that contains highlighted words

Tags: php, search, replace, search-engine, highlight

I am creating a search engine for my web app. Now I want to highlight the results found for user search request. I have the following function:

```
function highlight($text, $words) {
    foreach ($words as $word) {
            $word = preg_quote($word);              
            $text = preg_replace("/\b($word)\b/i", '<span class="highlighted">\1</span>', $text);               
    }

    return $text;
```

}

It is working well but I don't want the whole text to appear in search results page, because it can be thounds of lines of text, so I want to show only part of it that has highlighted words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this solution? It uses `preg_match_all()` to get all occurrences of the word and displays max 10 characters left or right of it but highlights only the matched word

```
$text = <<<EOF
hello_world sdfsdf
sd fsdfdsf hello_world
 hello_world
safdsa
EOF;

$word = preg_quote('hello_world');
$text = preg_match_all("~\b(.{0,10})($word)(.{0,10})\b~is", $text, $matches);

for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
    echo '<p>'
       . $matches[1][$i]
       . '<span class="hl">'
       . $matches[2][$i]
       . '</span>'
       . $matches[3][$i]
       . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: what function can I use for callback?

Comment: he wants to limitate the text and not replacing something? how does this function prevent the text being thousands of signs long?

Comment: @user2458684 I understood that he wants to *highlight* only the first words. Check my update

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it did not solve my problem. I want to highlight the full word, not 3 chars of the word. And my main problem is to print out the part of the text in which there is highlighted word. if I use substr($text, 0, 700); it will work but it might not show the highlihgted word if it is at the end of the large text

Comment: Check my update. Are you working for google? do you employ? :D

Comment: Now it is better. I don't work for Google, and this is not for commercial app, but I got inspiration from Google Search ;)